# document.getElementsByName("q1").disabled = true not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to disables inputs with the name `"q1"`, however It just doesn't disable them.

The line of code is just

```
if (time < 0){
    document.getElementById("lose").innerHTML = "O tempo acabou!";
    document.getElementById("nextQuestion").style.display = "block"
    document.getElementsByName("q1").disabled = true
}
```

The other `document.getElementById` work.

The html is

```
<br><br><input type="submit" name="q1" value="arroz">
            <input type="submit" name="q1" value="massa"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="q1" value="Apanhado em flagrante">
            <input type="submit" name="q1" value="batata de tremoços"><br><br><br>`
```

Comment: `getElementsByName` returns collection.  Perhaps you meant `document.getElementsByName("q1")[0].disabled`?

Comment: document.getElementsByName("q1") returns list of elements with name q1, so you should loop and disable

Comment: You have lot's of inputs with the name 'q1', so you should probably make them each unique. Or get the proper index

Comment: Oh, I didn't know it returned a list, I was expecting it to just disable them all. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementsByName` returns a [NodeList](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodelist.asp), which is sort of like an array. You need to loop through it and disable each element.

The [NodeList](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodelist.asp) would contain all the elements that have the name `q1`, and the code below (specifically the [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop) will disable each element with the name of `q1`

```js
time = -1;

if (time < 0){
    document.getElementById("lose").innerHTML = "O tempo acabou!";
    document.getElementById("nextQuestion").style.display = "block"
    document.getElementsByName("q1").forEach(e => {
      e.disabled = true;
    });
}
```

```html
<br><br><input type="submit" name="q1" value="arroz">
<input type="submit" name="q1" value="massa"><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="q1" value="Apanhado em flagrante">
<input type="submit" name="q1" value="batata de tremoços"><br><br><br>
<div id="lose"></div>
<div id="nextQuestion"></div>
```

Comment: The e in the foreach loop is each element of q1 right?

Comment: @DuarteArribas yes. In foreach loops, we usually use `element` to signify that it's the element. I've started using `e` which is easier to type, but means the same thing